# Error Twig while generating slug, parameters missing ("slug") to generate a URL

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to render my Twig product-page and its url-slug. My controller:

```
* @Route("/item/{id}", name="app_showitem_getid", requirements={"id": "\d+"})
* @param int $id
* @return Response
* @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
public function getid(int $id):Response

{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Item::class);
    $item = $repository->findBy($id);

    return $this->render("item/prodpage.html.twig", ["items"=>$item]);
}
```

and

```
* @Route("/item/{slug}", name="app_showslug_getslug")
* @return Response
* @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
public function getslug(string $slug)

{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $em->getRepository(Item::class);

    $itemSlug = $repository->findBy(["slug"=>$slug]);

    $this->generateUrl('app_showslug_getslug', [array("slug"=> array($itemSlug))],UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
}
```

File routes.yaml:

```
app_item_getid:
    path:/item/{id}
    controller: App\Controller\ShowitemController::getid
    requirements:
        id:'\d+'
```

My template.html.twig doc:

```
{% for item in items%}
    -->This link target the product-page:
      "{{ path('app_showitem_getid', {'id': item.id}) }}"
{% endfor%}
```

How can I generate a template.twig thats targets item's product-page by id and its slug ?
I can not render product-page correctly as it throws "parameters missing" error but its slug is there, in url!
What's missing  ?

Comment: I can't see the action where you render `template.html.twig`

Comment: I put "item" to replace my original object. But in general functions and objects woks.

Comment: You mean: $this->generateUrl ()?

Comment: I return the product-page("in a html.twig" [items=>$item])

Comment: And can you render by id correctly? Missing return in getSlug?

Comment: But how to generateUrl in the same product-page? = ('app_showslug_getslug', [array("slug"=>array($itemslug))]) ???

Comment: Anyway I shouldn't recommend using the same route for different things. You could use item/id/{id} and item/slug/{slug}, or use one as item/{whatever}

Comment: My function getSlug() renders just the slug in Url but not may product-page!

Comment: because you're not returning it

Comment: In official doc, section Routing, it is written to use a route, as id has requirements{"page"='"\d+"}... ? I'll try to change "item" by "object"..to avoid using same @Route...

Comment: so is it possible to write : return->this->generateUrl() ???

Comment: Not yet. $item = $repository->find($id); modified... but no slug in url.          New route name = @Route("/product/{slug}")... not working            So how do I render 1 simple product-page and it's slug ?

Comment: Yes, you can return a `$this->generateUrl()`. By the way, I can't see the `getSlug()` call. Is is supposed to be bellow `{{ path('app_showitem_getid', {'id': item.id}) }}`?

Comment: @Manolo, I saw the sample in oficial site, but is it correct to write two href ?with two "app_paths", I'm not sure !

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you add the code where you're calling getSlug

Comment: I wanted to share my error: as I nested the href ="{{path..}}" into another href= "{{path}}"  word link" ... The answer was easy now it works :{{ ,...{'id': item.id, 'slug': item.slug}) }}. I used the same route aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I think here:

```
public function getid(int $id):Response
{
    ***********************************
    $item = $repository->find($id);
    ***********************************
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `getid($id)` is the controller action it appears to be from the `@Route` comment above it, you can have the framework automatically fetch the item entity from the database, if it was unique.

```
public function getIdAction(Item $id)
{
    var_dump($id);  // $id instanceof Item::class
    // with $id->getId() or $id->id (if public), etc.
}
```

If id or $slug was unique, you can also `-findOneBy(...)` to get a single item back, instead of an array with just 1 item.

Comment: In my case, id= slug as it is the title of the product. I see my slug in url but I can not see the page. Sorry for delay,  cache:clear takes 10 mins to execute.

Comment: findOneBy($slug); not yet. Does the function generateUrl() target to my html.twig product-page automatically ?

Comment: If slug can not return a template how to associate it to my first route get product-page by id ?

Comment: if I change findOneBy($slug), it throws "must be of the type array", so I have to come back to first version: findBy(["slug"=>$slug])